# Communicating between a Camera Plugin and a Model Plugin

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My goal is to use the camera to plugin and develop a simple image processing program which finds a red ball in the frame and it determines the center position of the ball.

Once my camera determines these coordinates I need a model plugin to work based on the position of the ball. Basically determining the angle to turn.

Q1 ) How do i communicate between these two plugins ?

Q2 ) Are there tutorials for this ?

-Thanks
Bharadwaj

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2654/communicating-between-a-camera-plugin-and-a-model-plugin/) by [Bharadwaj Ramesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154/bharadwaj-ramesh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can communicate using gztopic messages using the gazebo::transport system. There are two example programs that use gazebo::transport, [publisher](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/c21a92eb17f903c63ddb1a6502942ab5e46d2836/examples/stand_alone/publisher?at=default) and [listener](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/c21a92eb17f903c63ddb1a6502942ab5e46d2836/examples/stand_alone/listener?at=default). You should be able to replicate this code in your plugins using [gazebo's built-in protobuf message types](http://gazebosim.org/msgs.html) to accomplish your goal. Feel free to keep asking if you need more guidance.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bharadwaj Ramesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154/bharadwaj-ramesh/) on 2013-05-03**:
Hay scpeters : Thanks a lot ! THose are exactly the codes I am looking at. Thanks.
I will basically be sending a angular data from my camera plugin to my model plygin, which I would expect to be a float data. But I see an integer type of message but not float or double type of message sendable. Should I be creating a custom message for this ?

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-03**:
It would be easier to use a part of a Vector2d or Vector3d message.

**Comment by [Bharadwaj Ramesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154/bharadwaj-ramesh/) on 2013-05-03**:
I'm tryin to make a custom message using the following tutorial,but its not workin

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/256f98f2318b/examples/plugins/custom_messages?at=default

I tried changing the main(the one that connects to the .cc file) CMakeLists.txt file to:

link_directories(${GAZEBO_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/msgs)

I did that change to CMake file from the following tutorial :

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.4/custom_messages
do you kno wats wrong

**Comment by [Bharadwaj Ramesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154/bharadwaj-ramesh/) on 2013-05-04**:
Hay cah you please check this post and help me with figuring what is wrong :

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2676/simple-subscribing-plugin/